# transition in javascript doesnt start

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition

I have the strangest issue i have ever seen - hope you can help me guys.

I am making rainbow text transition in my chrome packaged app. You can see it

```js
// script2.js
var box = document.getElementById('kalreg');
box.addEventListener('transitionend', loopTransition, false )

function loopTransition(e) {
  if ( e.propertyName == 'color' ) {
    console.log('aa');

    if (box.className == "it-animate") {
      console.log('bb');
      $(box).removeClass("it-animate")
    } else {
      box.className = "it-animate";
      console.log('cc');
    }
  }
}

box.className = ''
```

```css
.it-wrapper{
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 1140px;

}
.it-wrapper h3{
  font-size: 130px;
  line-height: 150px;
  padding: 30px 30px 40px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  font-family: 'guanine', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(105,94,127,0.54) 0%,
    rgba(255,92,92,0.57) 15%,
    rgba(255,160,17,0.59) 27%,
    rgba(252,236,93,0.61) 37%,
    rgba(255,229,145,0.63) 46%,
    rgba(111,196,173,0.65) 58%,
    rgba(106,132,186,0.67) 69%,
    rgba(209,119,195,0.69) 79%,
    rgba(216,213,125,0.7) 89%,
    rgba(216,213,125,0.72) 100%), 
    -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.9), transparent 20px, rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 40px);

  background-size: 300% 100%;
  background-position: center left, top left;

  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;

  transition: all 2s ease;

  -moz-border-radius: 90px 15px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.4); 
}
.it-wrapper h3.it-animate{
  background-position: center right, top right;
  color: rgba(255,137,149,0.7);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px rgba(39,137,149, 0.9);

}





input {
  width: 100%;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: guanine;
  src: local(guanine), url('fonts/guanine_.ttf') format('opentype');
}
```

```html
<div class="it-wrapper">
  <h3 class="it-animate" id="kalreg">text</h3>
</div>
```

working in jsfiddle here:
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gccscpuh/)

If you press "run" rainbow would move. And here goes the strangest part. On my computer this animation doesnt start although files look identically except one small difference - i include script2.js (commented in html file in fiddle) instead of raw javascript in html file. But there is a way to start animation on ma computer. All I need to do is instead of last line in javascript that looks like this:

```
box.className = ''
```

put something like this:

```
setTimeout(function () { box.className = ''}, 0)
```

I have no idea what is going on here, especially everything worked fine yesterday. Any ideas ? I am sitting with this all evening and cant find any reason why it behaves like that.

Kalreg

Comment: Your fiddle is set up such that the JavaScript code runs in a "load" handler. Is that how your stand-alone page works?

Comment: I have two files - window.html that has all css and html that you can see in fiddle. Javascript is located in file script2.js and it is loaded from window html using <script src="script2.js"></script>

Comment: Great. Is the code in your `script2.js` file wrapped in a window "load" event handler? If not, then that may be your problem, because jsFiddle is doing that for you.

Comment: I am not sure what word 'wrapped' means in that context, can you elaborate ?

Comment: `window.onload = function() { /* all your code here */ };`

Comment: chrome packaged app doesnt let me for security reasons to put working code in window.html file but fortunately i coded it into js file and... it works like charm! thank you so much!